# how can I access system properties using spring boot and Liquibase changeset yaml file

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot, liquibase

A Spring Boot Java application using Liquibase to manage the database schema changes is started with a parameter (e.g. dev, int) specifying the environment it runs in.

There are corresponding properties files (e.g. dev.properties, int.properties) which define properties for the corresponding environment.

So in dev.properties there is e.g.

```
url.info=http://dev.app.info
```

and in tst.properties there is

```
url.info=http://tst.app.info
```

The application reads in the properties from the file corresponding to the passed in parameter.

This mechanism works fine when the application is deployed and started in each environment.  There are many instances when the corresponding property is used.

However, it doesn't work with a Liquibase yaml changeset containing the following insert statement

```
- insert:
        tableName: result
        columns:
          - column:
              name: id
              value: a88b6708-5c9f-40c4-a3ca-41e7a6b57fc8
          - column:
              name: infoUrl
              value: ${url.info}
```

I have tried double and single quotes in the yaml file, i.e. "${url.info}" and '${url.info}' but the database always ends up with the String ${url.info}

Is there another notation I have to use for properties in yaml files?
or
Can properties not be referenced in liquibase yaml files the way they can with xml files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you are using Spring Boot, you can use its `application.properties` file to define [change log parameters](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html).

Any property with a name that begins with `liquibase.parameters.` can be referenced in a changelog. For example, the property `liquibase.parameters.url.info` can be referenced as `${url.info}` in your changelog (YAML or XML).

To use different configuration files for dev, QA, production etc you can use profiles and profile-specific configuration files. For example, the `application-dev.properties` file will only be loaded when the `dev` profile is active.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy.   Modifying the property to be **liquibase.parameters.url.info** did change the behaviour but am now getting an message - org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'parameters[url.info]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Bean property 'parameters[url.info]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: What version of Boot are you using? The parameters support is new in 1.3.

Comment: Yep, I was debugging the Spring code and saw there were no parameters in the LiquibaseProperties class.  Will upgrade and try again.  Cheers

Comment: sorry for commenting on old question.
`spring.liquibase.parameters.param: value` ---> will be used like this `${param}` ?
I tried this but it does not work

Comment: @AmirChoubani you have to replace `:` by `=` so `spring.liquibase.parameters.param= value` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Any from answer above.
Just to make it clearer: your full param name in your `application.yaml` should look like:

```
spring:
liquibase:
  parameters:
    paramName: paramValue
```

And then you can refer it in liquibase changeset as `${paramName}` in my case