# Access value application.properties of spingboot inside Liquibase mongodb xml changelog

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, liquibase

I need to set a base url in application.properties of springboot and need to insert record into mongodb in liquibase with that base url

Tried something like below

in application.properties

```
liquibase.parameters.url.info=http://www.google.com/
```

in insert Changelog.xml file

```
<ext:insertOne collectionName="test">
  <ext:document>
    {
      "url": ${url.info} // tried "${url.info}" as well
    }
  </ext:document>
</ext:insertOne>
```

Tried all options. Refereed link https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-property-substitution.html

Could anyone please help on this
Using spring boot, Liquibase and mongodb

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326981/how-can-i-access-system-properties-using-spring-boot-and-liquibase-changeset-yam) help in some way?

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot, the property should begin with [spring.liquibase.parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data-migration.spring.liquibase.parameters). In this case, the property should be named `spring.liquibase.parameters.url.info`