# Liquibase system properties in changeSet with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot application which uses Liquibse to manage the database schema changes.

I have the following change set:

```
<changeSet id="add-customer-entry" context="dev">
    <insert tableName="customer">
        <column name="email" value="${email}"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

I'm trying to pass the values to the email property with no success. The following works;

```
<property name="email" value="some-email"/>
```

But I need to set the value either as a property in the application-local.properties file or as a JVM system property.

I defined the property in the application-local.properties file like this:

```
spring.liquibase.parameters.email=some-email
```

And in IntelliJ IDE in the program arguments like this: --Dliquibase.email=some-email

No success, the value in the email column is stored as ${email}

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.2.8.RELEASE and the liquibase version is 3.8.9

I followed the following post;

[how can I access system properties using spring boot and Liquibase changeset yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326981/how-can-i-access-system-properties-using-spring-boot-and-liquibase-changeset-yam)

Comment: do you have the same behaviour if you put the property values as liquibase.parameters.email? refer to this stackoverflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326981/how-can-i-access-system-properties-using-spring-boot-and-liquibase-changeset-yam